# failed to install app in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have developed a simple application in `Xamarin forms`. It is running properly on android emulator in my PC.

I have archived the android project and generated apk for that however it is not installing in my android phone. The error message is

> failed to install the app

I have mostly used the default configuration values while building the app and archiving.

Only these are the configuration which I have changed:

1. Inside `Android Option` **Unchecked** the `Use Shared the runtime`.
2. and in `Linking` changed `none` to `Sdk assemblies only`.
3. `Configuration` is **Debug** and platform is **Active(Any CPU)**.
   Although I tried installing app with all three value including
   `Debug, Release, Active(Debug)` but none of them installed.

What is wrong here?

Comment: did you put your phone in developer mode and allow USB debugging?

Comment: @Taier Yes my phone's developer mode is on and USB debugging is checked.

Comment: good, then try the golden path. Close Xamarin Stuido, open it back, clean the project, rebuild and then deploy :) ah. also check the min verison on your project and your android version!

Comment: @Taier though my android phone version is `Lollipop` and min version is `Jelly bean`.

Comment: then open device monitor (should be in Android SDK) and look to the logs of the device on the installation process. There definitely should be an additional description to the error.

Comment: Does it work on the Android Emulator?

Comment: @jamesfdearborn I have mentioned in question. It is working fine in android emulator.

Comment: @Taier Not worked! Any possible solution??

Comment: If it's ever been installed on the device, it's worth uninstalling it.  We found at one stage that our app showed on the apps list by the bundle name, rather than the application name (which it normally shows as). So have a check for both application name, and bundle name, and if found, uninstall.

Answer (score 6):

Try changing the Android Package Format to APK

Comment: Visual studio cannot install the app when the package format is set to bundle or aab

Answer (score 0):

Likely you have not gone on to "distribute" your app. All apps (even personal and private apps) have to be signed with a digital certificate (this is done for you when deploying and debugging in a local Visual Studio Session).

In order to deploy a 'release' build of your app, archive the app and then press 'distribute'. Choose 'AdHoc' and create a new certificate for your app. This should then allow the app to be installed on your device. There is no cost associated with this;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/?tabs=windows